# compare hash of hashes and return lowest value of specific key in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
h = { "C6"=>
      { "G1"=>{"term_difference"=>15.1, "spread"=>7.6 },
        "G2"=>{"term_difference"=>13.7, "spread"=>7.0 },
        "G3"=>{"term_difference"=>8.2, "spread"=>6.0 },
        "G4"=>{"term_difference"=>4.0, "spread"=>3.8 },
        "G5"=>{"term_difference"=>0.9, "spread"=>1.8 }
      }
    }
```

What I need to do is return a hash that looks like this:

```
{ "C6"=>
  {
   "G5"=>{"term_difference"=>0.9, "spread"=>1.8}
  }
}
```

The result is the hash with the lowest `term_difference` value.

I've been trying to figure this out but can't seem to crack it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h.map { |k,v| [k, [v.min_by { |_,v| v["term_difference"] }].to_h ] }.to_h 
  #=> {"C6"=>{"G5"=>{"term_difference"=>0.9, "spread"=>1.8}}}
```

Comment: More generally: `Hash[h.map { |k, v| [k, [v.min_by { |_,v| v["term_difference"] }].to_h ] }]`

Comment: Note: `#to_h` is available for Ruby 2.x or greater versions.

Comment: @Surya, yes. I regularly mentioned that for a couple of years until it just became too tiresome. :-)

Comment: @Amadan. Good suggestion. I've used it. Thanks.

Comment: @Surya: 1.9 was end-of-lifed at February 23, 2015, we should just assume everyone works on 2.x at this point (and if they're not, it's their own fault).

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland ! Answer is correct and accepted!! :) :) :)